# Store email and password in database

Tags: php, mysql

I use the following code to store the email and passwords in my database when logging in, but somehow it only stores the passwords.  The email field remains NULL in the database.  Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'XXXXXXX');
define('DB_USER', 'XXXXXXX');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXX');
define('DB_HOST', 'db.example.com');

$link = mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
die('Could not Connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['email'];
$value = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (email) VALUES ('$value')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (password) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: what does the form look like?

Comment: Please try to remember to never post real connection info in a StackOverflow question.

Comment: I am interesting, what book you are learning from?

Comment: To follow up and support @MarcB's answer, check out this Apress book: http://www.amazon.com/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Experts-Source/dp/143022925X/ - I found it extremely useful.

Comment: well your interned is bad. and it seems you just don't understand the answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are first saying $value is the email adddress.  Then you are saying $value is the password.

So when you insert, $value is always going to be password.  Try renaming your variables.

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO demo (email, password) VALUES ("'.$email.'", "'.$password.'")';
```

Don't forget to secure for SQL injections.  Do some searching on SO for this.

Comment: Oops.  Forgot to put the standard SO message of "watch for SQL injection!"

Answer (score 4):

You are overwriting your variables

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$pass  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (email, password) VALUES ('$email, '$pass')";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$value = $_POST['email'];
$value = $_POST['password'];
```

The second assignment destroys/overwrites the first assignment, so this code is working as written... You'd need something like:

```
$value1 = $_POST['email'];
$value2 = $_POST['password'];
```

to store those separately. The same goes for your two $sql variables.

Beyond that, you're directly inserting user-provided data into an SQL query, meaning your code is gaping wide open for SQL injection attacks.

Given the basicness of these coding errors, I suggest you improve your coding skills before attempting to put something onto a public-facing webserver, or you're likely to get your site pwn3d in short order.

Comment: Check that your form is actually using the POST method, and that the form fields' names match what you're using in the $_POST references.

Comment: yeah the form field names match and i have used the Post method already.....but still it doesnt work....do u mean i sshud somethin like this:
$value1 = $_POST['email'];
$value2 = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (email) VALUES ('$email')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (password) VALUES ('$password')";

Comment: No, you still don't get it. if you have `$x = 1; $x = 2;`, you're not storing two values into $x, you're REPLACING the original 1 with a 2. Go learn basic coding first, please...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:

```
$value = $_POST['email'];
$value = $_POST['password'];
```

You are setting the value of the "$value" variable to the email, then resetting it to the password.

Try this:

```
$email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Then, make sure you only set SQL once:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (email,password) VALUES ('$email','$password')";
```

However, I would make sure to sanitize your input values too. Also, might want to edit your original post to remove your DB name, password, and host :)